# Sign webpage and JavaScript to protect against server manipulation

Tags: javascript, security

I would like to sign a whole webpage to protect against changes by a third party. Currently, end2end encryption with JavaScript does not make sense because an attacker with control over the server could change the code to send himself an unencrypted copy. For a user it is not possible to verify code he loads from the web is from the correct source.
Also with cloud and serverless becoming more popular you don't own the server anymore.

I know there is HTTPS and [SRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) but if the attacker has control over the server this offers no protection.

I would like to add a public key to the domain record like [DKIM](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-1.4). The browser should only accept signed files with the correct signature.

All I found was [XML Signature](https://www.w3.org/Signature/) but I as far I can tell there is no browser support at all. Still, this is not what I am looking for.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
W3C Draft or something?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a solution to this today. There are probably proposals, but nothing that would be usable in a browser *now*. The server is still the trusted entity.

Comment: I am also interested in a proposal if one exists.